# Laravel Sub-Domain Routing with Resource Controllers

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have set a wildcard subdomain and the subdomain name dynamically represent an account. I want to use this account name to check if the user can see a particular resource. I also want to use this account name in several controllers to print custom data about the account.

```php
Route::group(array('domain' => '{account}.mywebsite.com'), function()
{
    Route::group(array('before' => 'check_account'), function() // I want to use $account in check_account filter
    {
        Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
        Route::resource('docs', 'DocController'); // I want to use $account in this controller
    });
});
```

How can I use the `$account` variable in a filter and in a method of a resource controller ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access `$account` in `check_account` filter like

```
Route::filter('check_account', function($route){
    $account = $route->getParameter('account');
});
```

In your `DocController` you may access the `account` as

```
public function index($account)
{
    // $account is available here
}
```